# Displaying an array result with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my problem:

Everything works but I have a display that resembles ["1","2","3"]. I would like 1 2 3. I tried all to_ functions but that does not change ..

Thanks for your time.

model.rb:

```
validates :check, presence: true
validate :check_must_be_3

  private
    def checks_must_be_3
      if !check != 3
        errors[:base] << "You must select exactly 3 checks"
      end
    end
```

html:

```
<%= simple_form_for @answer do |f| %>
  <h3>Choose 3 answers</h3>
    <ul>
    <% (1..5).each do |x| %>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="answer[check][]" id="optionsCheckbox<%= x %>" value="<%= x %>" />
          <%= x %>
        </label>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
private

def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit(check:[])
end
```

answer is a string in db.

Comment: ["1","2","3"] comes from DB ?

Comment: Not sure what is your question? Please do mention what problem you have, what you were expecting and what you got along with relevant code.

Comment: @ansar, in rails c the render is 1 2 3. but in html render i have ["1","2","3"]

Comment: If i use .join(" ") i have this problem. undefined method 'join' for "[\"14\", \"23\", \"32\", \"41\", \"48\"]":String Did you mean JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add below lines on your result

```
'["1", "2", "3"]'.split("[").pop().split("]").first.tr!('"', '')
```

Not the best way but will work for you

One other solution is

```
 '["1", "2", "3"]'.reverse.chop.reverse.chop.tr!('""', '')
```

Comment: `map` is redundant. Anyway,it is better to use `map(&:to_i)`

Comment: in html i hav this problem: undefined method 'map' for "[\"14\", \"23\", \"32\", \"41\", \"48\"]":String Did you mean?  tap